# Help me open my thermostatic shower mixer to replace cartridge

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

So the thermostatic dial has ceased up and I want to open it to order and replace the cartridge. Trouble is I can't get it open!

What I have done:

**Top handle**

Unscrewed the nipple with pliars and rag

Unscrewed the hex screw behind it(and it fell in)

Pulled / jimmy'd and twisted but the handle wouldn't come off.

**Bottom handle**

Removed the screw cover and hex screw which is opposite the nipple

Tried and failed to unscrew the nipple and scratched it a bit (it is sprung loaded so maybe it isn't supposed to unscrew)

Pulled / jimmy'd and twisted but the handle wouldn't come off.

What am I missing?! Am I fighting rust? If I just need more force then how can I do it without damaging the chrome?
Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: did you check the manufacturer's web site?

Comment: @jsotola I don't know who the manufacturer is.

Comment: Have you tried gentle taps on the face of the handle? Like if you were installing it, to try and loosen any buildup of deposits or rust.

Comment: @Jeff that worked for the bottom handle but not the top handle. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, other than keep trying....maybe try vinegar sprayed up behind the handle, or some WD-40 like penetrating oil. Tap and twist and tap and twist....